# Live Data and 2-Way Data Binding: Custom setter not being called

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am using 2-way data binding to update a LiveData String object from my ViewModel with a string set in the EditText:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
  android:id="@+id/writeReviewTitle"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@={viewModel.liveReviewTitle}"
/>
```

So, from my understanding, the `ViewModel` would have its `liveReviewTitle` attribute updated every time the text changed in the EditText. I assume this is happening through the usage of a TextWatcher or some sort of listening mechanism that is being taken care of for me by the library. I also thought that when the text needed to be updated, it would have its `setter` called. **Which does not seem to be the case**! When the text changes, I need to do some more stuff in my ViewModel, therefore I implemented a custom `setter` for `liveReviewTitle`, but it is **not being called** (I tried debugging).
This is how it looks like in the `ViewModel` class:

```
var liveReviewTitle: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            customLogicHere()
        }
```

Tried debugging this `setter` but it never seems to be called! What is happening here? Feels a little confusing. The text is being updated, and it is saved in the `ViewModel`, it is just the `setter` that is not called.

Comment: Just follow this example : https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761

Comment: @NSimon that example is not using the real 2-way data binding provided by the library. The developer is creating the listeners and attaching them hilself, which is something I want to avoid, as the library should be taking care of this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course it's never called, you're not setting a new MutableLiveData, you're setting a new String value inside the MutableLiveData (possibly with `setValue`).

However, you should be able to intercept the value that's being set and execute custom logic after setting the value if you expose a MediatorLiveData instead of the MutableLiveData directly.

**EDIT:** the following should work as expected:

```
val liveReviewTitle: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
private val mediator = MediatorLiveData<String>().apply {
    addSource(liveReviewTitle) { value ->
        setValue(value)
        customLogicHere()
    }
}.also { it.observeForever { /* empty */ } }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I cant directly observe the live data (lets say, in the constructor for example), because I need a life cycle owner for that, right? That is why I need this mediator?

Comment: When I get back from Kotliners conf. I'll  write a sample

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can we still count on promised sample? I'm curious :)

Comment: I forgot. But I'll put something together when I get home from vacation. Remind me tomorrow, I never find this question XD

Comment: @KarolKulbaka man that was a bit dumber and more complicated than I expected. If you expose the MediatorLiveData to the databinding, then you cannot easily make the private MutableLiveData have the new value. If you expose the MutableLiveData, then MediatorLiveData is not active, so it does not subscribe to listen for changes of the MutableLiveData. So I had to add a dummy observer with `observeForever` to ensure that Mediator is active and properly intercepts the new values set for the MutableLiveData.

Comment: How do I clean up the "observerForever"? Is it with: mediator.removeObserver{ mediator } ?

Comment: @Minsky you don't need to clean it up I think because this is created once and dies along with the ViewModel, but if you feel icky about it then you'd have to store a reference to the empty lambda I passed in and then remove *that* in `onCleared()`.

Comment: I don't really understand your example. The MediatorLiveData is private, so how do you observe it from xml?

Comment: @AndroidKotlinNoob I didn't, I exposed the mutable variant, and the mediator is always observed as an internal subscription. I do wonder that this makes the original `liveReviewTitle` always active though...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I just realized that OP is not trying to change the value that gets set, only execute some code when it does get set. (Something I would have done with a `TextWatcher`). Okay, sorry. I was thinking of a completely different problem.

Answer (score 8):

@EpicPandaForce solution is proper but in `EditText` two way binding can be obtained in much simpler way.
Add attribute `afterTextChanged` to your widget as below:

`android:afterTextChanged="@{viewModel::doLogic}"`

Then in your `ViewModel` class just write method:

`fun doLogic(s: Editable) {
  //update Livedata or do other logic
 }`

**EDIT**

I have missed important documentation [note](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#top_of_page). Much easier (and far more proprer) will be:

```
android:text="@={viewModel.someLivedata}
```

and then in our `LifecycleOwner` class we can update value of liveData everywhe when we need, and of course we can react on changes from registered observer.

Comment: This is the simplest most correct answer. I can't believe that with so documentation I read, they fail to mention this. it is always @{}

Comment: Omg!!! I lost 2 days trying to know what happened and my problem was the "=" after @. Thanks @chitgoks

Comment: Dang it! I did the same. Guys please note that `"@={viewModel.someLivedata}"` instead of just `"@{viewModel.someLivedata}"`.

Comment: I used two way data binding this way and its working fine, However when I'm observing the same LiveData object inside my fragment, the observe method is getting called continuosly without me changing anything to the EditText. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure. There may be a few reason of such behaviour. What exactly do you mean 'called continuosly'?

Answer (score 4):

@EpicPandaForce is right about your setter, it's for the `MutableLiveData` itself and not the value it's holding. So your `LiveData` should be a `val`, no need for it to be a `var`, and the framework should do the right thing as long as you set a `LifecycleOwner` on the binding. You could add another `Observer` to your `LiveData` in place of a custom setter to add your custom logic.

Comment: I can't observe the live data from within the View Model, as it is not a life cycle owner. Will have the use the Mediator for that, as the accepted answer suggested!

Comment: You could use `observeForever` if your internal custom logic doesn't need to be lifecycle aware. But `MediatorLiveData` might be the more robust approach depending on your use case.

Comment: Since the mediator is also not life cycle aware the observe forever might just do the job easier.

Comment: I had not set the LifecycleOwner of the binding. This fixed it. Thank you!